# How to implement Javascript String.fromCharCode in Python3 to accept a minus

Tags: python, ascii

I have to make a character in Python like the following Javascript code:

```js
char = String.fromCharCode(-31)
console.log(char);
```

Here is my code:

```py
chr(-31)
```

But I got error in python:`ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)`

I know the problem is passing a minus number into the `chr` function, but I don't know witch function able to process the minus number.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that Python's behaviour is better here: you're passing in something that doesn't have a defined Unicode code point!  That said, [the JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) say:

> A sequence of numbers that are UTF-16 code units. The range is between 0 and 65535 (0xFFFF). Numbers greater than 0xFFFF are truncated. No validity checks are performed.

So in Python you'd just do:

```py
chr(-31 & 0xffff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there isn't really a `chr()` function in Python that supports receiving a negative number. JavaScript behaviour is odd and it shouldn't really be accepting a negative number for this as that doesn't make sense.

What it's actually doing is wrapping around to 65535, which you can see with:

```
char = String.fromCharCode(-31)
console.log(char.charCodeAt()) // 65505

char = String.fromCharCode(-1)
char.charCodeAt() // 65535
```

So what you can do if you need to take in negative numbers in Python is use `65536-<number>` e.g.

```
>>> chr(65536-31)
'￡'
```